# Capacitive negative feedback in common-source stage

Tags: cmos, feedback

[image]

The author is describing the benefits of feedback circuits with this example.

He first states (marked 1) to at low frequencies C2 draws a negligible current from the output node, thus not affecting the low frequency gain. I agree.

However, he then proceeds to calculate current through C2 and C1 (marked 2).

Doesn't that just contradict 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small signal approximation means that signal dependent parameters are considered constant.

The current through \$C_{2}\$ is negligible relative to \$I_{D}\$ so from \$ro_{1}\$'s point of view \$I_{D}\$ does not change. \$ro_{1}\$ and \$gm\$ can be considered constant.

From the point of view of the capacitors and the input, the current through \$C_{2}\$ **is significant**. The current does cause voltage drop across \$ro_{1}\$ but the contribution of the current to \$I_{D}\$ **is negligible**.